# maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am using following code.

```
    private List<Dependency> getDependencies(QuestionnaireTemplate questionnaireTemplate) {        
        CustomSearchCriteria dependCriteria = new CustomSearchCriteria(Dependency.class)
        def dependProj = ['id']
        dependProj.each { item ->
            dependCriteria.projections.add(new CustomProjection(item))
        }
        dependCriteria.expressions.add
        (new CustomExpression('dependencyToReqVals.requirementValue.requirement.section.template.id', questionnaireTemplate.id, "="))
        def depensWithId = searchByCriteria(dependCriteria)

        List<Dependency> result = []
        if (depensWithId) {
            def criteria = Dependency.createCriteria()
            result = criteria.listDistinct {
                'in'('id', depensWithId.collect{it.id})
                fetchMode('dependencyToReqVals', FetchMode.JOIN)
            }            
        }
        result
    }
```

The dependency list is more than 1000. How do i handle this in above code using only hibernate. Can we have some logic in hibernate where it checks if the list size is more than 1000 then it handles it using some condition

The query that is generated is as follows. The subquery returns more than 1000 values

```
  select
           this_.TABLEQSDE_ID as TABLEQSDE1_91_1_,
           this_.version as version91_1_,
           this_.CREATED_BY as CREATED3_91_1_,
           this_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION4_91_1_,
           this_.LAST_UPD_DATE as LAST5_91_1_,
           this_.UPDATED_BY as UPDATED6_91_1_,
           this_.LOGICAL_STRUCTURE as LOGICAL7_91_1_,
           this_.memo as memo91_1_,
           this_.NAME as NAME91_1_,
           dependency2_.TABLEQSDE_ID as TABLEQSDE7_3_,
           dependency2_.TABLEQSDR_ID as TABLEQSDR1_3_,
           dependency2_.TABLEQSDR_ID as TABLEQSDR1_95_0_,
           dependency2_.version as version95_0_,
           dependency2_.CREATED_BY as CREATED3_95_0_,
           dependency2_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION4_95_0_,
           dependency2_.LAST_UPD_DATE as LAST5_95_0_,
           dependency2_.UPDATED_BY as UPDATED6_95_0_,
           dependency2_.TABLEQSDE_ID as TABLEQSDE7_95_0_,
           dependency2_.TABLEQSRV_ID as TABLEQSRV8_95_0_,
           dependency2_.TYPE as TYPE95_0_ 
       from
           TABLE_QST_SETUP_DEPENDENCY this_ 
       left outer join
           TABLE_QST_SETUP_DEP_TO_REQ_VAL dependency2_ 
               on this_.TABLEQSDE_ID=dependency2_.TABLEQSDE_ID 
       where
           this_.TABLEQSDE_ID in 
        (select
           this_.TABLEQSDE_ID as y0_ 
       from
           TABLE_QST_SETUP_DEPENDENCY this_ 
       left outer join
           TABLE_QST_SETUP_DEP_TO_REQ_VAL dependency1_ 
               on this_.TABLEQSDE_ID=dependency1_.TABLEQSDE_ID 
       left outer join
           TABLE_QST_SETUP_REQ_VALUE requiremen2_ 
               on dependency1_.TABLEQSRV_ID=requiremen2_.TABLEQSRV_ID 
       left outer join
           TABLE_QST_SETUP_REQUIREMENT requiremen3_ 
               on requiremen2_.REQUIREMENT_TABLEQSRE_ID=requiremen3_.TABLEQSRE_ID 
       left outer join
           TABLE_QST_SETUP_SECTION section3x4_ 
               on requiremen3_.TABLEQSSC_ID=section3x4_.TABLEQSSC_ID 
       left outer join
           TABLE_QST_SETUP_TEMPLATE template4x5_ 
               on section3x4_.TABLEQSTE_ID=template4x5_.TABLEQSTE_ID 
       where
           template4x5_.TABLEQSTE_ID=789053796430);
```

Comment: So the data base server rejects this query if the subquery returns more than 1000 matches? And which programming language is this? Does not seem to be Java - maybe some template engine?

Comment: Yes oracle rejects more than 1000 arguments.This is groovy but the same logic can be applied to Java

Comment: I have got the solution

Comment: That's fine. For future readers it would be great if you would post and explain your solution as answer.